# Hibernate: Entity Relationship only with id in JSON?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I´ve got two Entities: User and Device.
Each Device should have one User. But the Users are already existing so I want to Link a User by the Id to my Device.
At the Moment I have to create a User and send it as Post-Request to my Backend. But I just want to send the Id which should be stored.

I have ceated an Application and have to transfer the Data via JSON-File

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private boolean activity;
    private boolean login;
```

```
Entity
@Table(name = "Devices")
public class Device {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id
    private boolean activity;
    private String location;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User owner;
```

```
//This is the JSON-File how I have to send it
{
    "activity": "true",
    "location": "Room 102",
    "owner": {
        "name": "Mike",
        "email": "testMail@test.com",
        "password": "123456",
        "activity": "true",
        "login": "false"
    }
}

//This is how I would like to send it (Only sending the Id of the other Table)
{
    "activity": "true",
    "location": "Room 102",
    "owner": "1"
}
```

I tried via Relationships (ManyToOne & OneToMany) but it didnt work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "didn't work"? What happened when you ran your code, and what were you expecting to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Comment: so why no add the field userId? so you can transfer to id to this field when deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you cna do is to keep sending the ownerId - as in your example. After that, you can map te other fields as usual, and, when it comes to the owner, use an `entityManager` or a `JpaRepository` and call the `getReference` method.

This will return something that looks like a `User` and it can be used for other queries or db operations, but it's actually just a proxy based on the given id:

```
User owner = entityManager.getReference(User.class, deviceDto.getOwner());
Device device = mapper.map(deviceDto); // map the other fields
device.setOwner(owner);
deviceRepository.save(device);
```

Read more about it here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-manager-get-reference

Comment: Can you show or explain me where I have to Implement this Codesnippet? In the Service Class?